# pdfLaTex - do not compile when line too long

Tags: pdftex, latexmk, compilation-error

I'm trying to compile a `.tex` file with `latexmk -outdir=output -pdf main.tex`. 
I've a long text that should take two line (in the pdf), but when I'm trying to compile I get this error:

```
pdfTeX error (font expansion): auto expansion is only possible with scalable fonts.
<argument> ...shipout:D \box_use:N \l_shipout_box
```

When I split the text (using `//`), everything works fine, but I want it to be automatic. 
Is there any way for that to happend?

Thank you!

Comment: you are using microtype and your document has some bitmap fonts.